# Laravel Missing required parameters for [Route: login]

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to have a locale variable in my views that sets the language, but i keep having an error.

Web.php

```
    Route::get('/login/{locale}', function ($locale){
    App::setLocale($locale);
    return view('auth.login')->with('locale', $locale);
})->name('login');

    Route::get('/register/{locale}', function ($locale){
    App::setLocale($locale);
    return view('auth.register')->with('locale', $locale);
})->name('register');
```

This two pages work fine setting the language, but when i try to make a post i get this error :

**Missing required parameters for [Route: login] [URI: login/{locale}].**

`Route::post('/teste', 'HomeController@store')->name('teste');`

`<form method="post" action="{{ route('teste')}}">`

And if i try to pass the locale variable like this :

`return view('auth.register', $locale);`

I get this error :

**array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array**

Comment: `Missing required parameters for [Route: login] [URI: login/{locale}` means this error you getting from a login route, which you write on a controller or a view.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what are you asking about  your routes, but when using the view() method the second parameter needs to be an array it should be more like this

```
return view('auth.register', ['locale' => $locale]);
```

Comment: Yeah nvm, i was forgeting to pass the variable like that. But i still dont know how to fix the other error.

Comment: Can you let me know in which line are you getting the `Missing required parameters for [Route: login] [URI: login/{locale}].`

Comment: The error goes to F:\laragon\www\Texter\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Exceptions\UrlGenerationException.php:17

Comment: You are using `route('login')` somewhere

Comment: The only route login i have is up there in the controller and its only used once when i click the login button it just redirects me to the login page

Comment: it's in web.php****

Answer (score 0):

I see that you defined Get routes for login and register, make sure you define also the POST routes for login and register.

```
Route::post('/login', 'AuthController@login')->name('login.submit');
Route::post('/register', 'AuthController@register')->name('register.submit');
```